# Bring object to the front in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, position, z-index

I try to use only one `<canvas>` element

[image]

1 : Clip a image

2 : Make one more rectangle

But **How to bring that rectangle to the front ?**

---

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('example');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = document.createElement('IMG');
image.onload = function () {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(29, 96);
    ctx.lineTo(157, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(288, 93);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
};
image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/500/500/';



// This

ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/yW86d/

Comment: Just one additional after-thought.  You can use compositing to draw new images behind existing images.  When you set context.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over" your red rect will be drawn behind the existing triangle. (Note: the new rect will only be drawn into transparent pixels)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

draw the rectangle after image has been drawn

i modified your code. try this,

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('example');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = document.createElement('IMG');
image.onload = function () {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(29, 96);
    ctx.lineTo(157, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(288, 93);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fill();
};
image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/500/500/';
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript canvas the last element drawn is on top, thus you cant use z-index to arrange your elements, you just have to draw them in the order you want them to appear.
For example if you want an element to be all the way in the back - draw it first, and if you want an element to be on top of every other element - draw it last.

Your code will look something like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('example');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = document.createElement('IMG');
image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/500/500/';


ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();
image.onload = function () {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(29, 96);
        ctx.lineTo(157, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(288, 93);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();
};
```

The image is drawn after the rectangle, so its on top :)